# How to set a proxy on bosh-cli

Tags: proxy, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I'm trying to upload a bosh release into the director. I use a Virtualbox environment and I'm behind a corporate proxy.

Even when I've tried to set the proxy with

```
export https_proxy=http://myproxy:3128
```

or with

```
export BOSH_ALL_PROXY=http://myproxy:3128
```

I never manage to do any download 
Does someone know how to do ?

```
MBP-de-Olivier:bosh-deployment olivier$ bosh -e vbox upload-release https://bosh.io/d/github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release?v=283
Using environment '192.168.50.6' as client 'admin'
Task 13

Task 13 | 15:28:45 | Downloading remote release: Downloading remote release (00:00:05)
               L Error: Failed to open TCP connection to bosh.io:443 (Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2) for "bosh.io" port 443)
Task 13 | 15:28:50 | Error: Failed to open TCP connection to bosh.io:443 (Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2) for "bosh.io" port 443)
```

Comment: I've seen that error "Address family not supported by protocol" outside of BOSH when ipv6 is disabled, but /etc/hosts has IPv6 format IPs.  I'm not sure if bosh-lite has ipv6 config and thats not supported by your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to download the release locally and upload to your bosh director from local host.

Comment: I agree that I can do it by this way and it works fine as workaround but  I don't understand why it doesn't work by upload directly with the bosh upload-release command

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the following lines:

```
export http_proxy=http://yourproxy:3128
export https_proxy=http://yourproxy:3128
```

Are you sure that `3128` is the correct port? This seems as if you are using cntlm (or another similar local proxy). If it is a local proxy: Is the service running? Can the service connect to the corporate proxy?

Comment: Yes I'm sure as i use this proxy port to configure my firefox to be able to go on internet. It's a corporate proxy.

Comment: Did you also set both environment variables?

Comment: Yes I add http_proxy and https_proxy

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the BOSH director does not know it must use a proxy. I'm under the impression you tried to configure the proxy at the bosh-cli level, but the download is performed by the director itself.

You could try to [re-deploy the director](https://bosh.io/docs/bosh-lite.html) with your proxy configuration. You can use [this ops file](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-deployment/blob/master/misc/proxy.yml) in order to do so.